# how can i duplicate the last element and insert it in the same array

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="ofertas container-cards-v2-2022">
     <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_1"></div>
     <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_2"></div>
     <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_3"></div>
     <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_4"></div>
</div>

var cards = ofertas.querySelectorAll('.card-component-v2-2022');
var array = [];
var id = 0;
```

here I restore the last card and insert it into a new array

```
var last_card_old = cards[cards.length - 1];
cards.forEach(function (card) {array.push(card);})
array.push(last_card_old);
```

it would stay like this

```
<div class="ofertas container-cards-v2-2022">
 <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_1"></div>
 <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_2"></div>
 <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_3"></div>
 <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_4"></div>
 <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_4"></div>
</div>
```

Now I rescue the last element again to modify the id so that the numbering continues

```
var last_card_new  = array[array.length - 1];
last_card_new.setAttribute('id', 'card_' + id + '_' + (array.length + 1));
array.push(last_card_new);
```

but the problem is that when consulting the array I change the last 2 elements, not the last one as I intended.

```
console.log(array);

<div class="ofertas container-cards-v2-2022">
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_1"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_2"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_3"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_6"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_6"></div>
</div>
```

but what i need is this

```
<div class="ofertas container-cards-v2-2022">
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_1"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_2"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_3"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_4"></div>
   <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are pushing a reference to an element. You are not making another DOM element by pushing it. If you want a new element, you would need to clone it and append it to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to try to make a duplicate of a DOM element, you need to make a copy of it. If not all you are doing is adding a new reference to the same element. So when you change that reference you change the element.

Below you select all the cards, we clone the last one, we change the id, and add it to the DOM.

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card-component-v2-2022");
const lastCard = cards[cards.length-1];
const card = lastCard.cloneNode();
card.id = lastCard.id.replace(/\d+$/, cards.length +1 );
lastCard.parentNode.append(card)
```

```css
.card-component-v2-2022 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}


.card-component-v2-2022::after {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<div class="ofertas container-cards-v2-2022">
  <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_1"></div>
  <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_2"></div>
  <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_3"></div>
  <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello this super, but if the div had content?

Comment: What do you mean if the div had content? If you do not want the content, then just generate a new div and add the class and id.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the methods the DOM provides

```js
const cloneAndAppendChild = parent => parent.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`,
  Object.assign(
    parent.lastElementChild.cloneNode(), 
    {id: parent.lastElementChild.id.replace(/\d+$/, parent.children.length + 1),
     textContent: ` => cloned from div#${parent.lastElementChild.id}`}
  ));

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
  cloneAndAppendChild(document.querySelector(`.container-cards-v2-2022`));
}
```

```css
.card-component-v2-2022:before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<div class="ofertas container-cards-v2-2022">
  <div class="card-component-v2-2022" id="card_0_1"></div>
</div>
```